# Create a staging WordPress Website in Microsoft Azure via Subdirectory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am trying to refresh a clients website with a brand new theme/template purchased from Themeforest. We will be using the Visual Composer plugin for the aesthetics of the website.

How do I create a staging website without disrupting the current live site on Microsoft Azure? And once finalized, switch to the new template?

And since this is Microsoft Azure, can I still log into WordPress and use the VC to create the customized layout without disrupting the live site via the staging website? (i.e. Dev.website.com vs. website.com)

I'm aware that there is the option to create another WordPress database and copy the code into the subdirectory, however I am not familiar with the Azure interface -  so how can I achieve this? Where can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature built into the platform that can help you with this. It's called Deployment slots, you can learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing

From your question it's not clear if your customer is already hosting his site in azure already. Also do you want the staging site going to the production database?

A good resource to get you started with Wordpress on App Service is this documentation: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/12/how-to-for-wordpress-on-app-service-windowslinux/

Comment: Thank you Byron. Is there another alternative rather than Deployment Slots? At the moment, my client only has a Basic Subrcription in Azure (upgrading to Standard or Premium is not an option). Also, yes, the client hosts the website in Azure (along with a third party like Network Solutions).